# Switching from Photoshop to GIMP - articles or guidance? 

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp

I've been using Photoshop CS3 since its release but I now do all my web work on Linux, and in the rare instances where I need to do any graphics work I have to swap onto another PC and then transfer the finished product to my other machines.

I have no intention of buying the latest version (CS5) as I no longer qualify for any discounts and the huge price tag is no good for me.

I'm having a couple of issues with GIMP that are probably just that I'm expecting different names or outcomes.

Are there any guides/articles about adjusting to using GIMP after being a competent Photoshop user?

Comment: "This is a guest post by professional photographer Scott Rowed, describing his experience in switching from Windows to Linux. " http://scienceblogs.com/gregladen/2010/07/linux_for_professional_photogr.php

Comment: If I owned a CS3, I'd try to get it running under Wine (http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=6584) or in a virtual machine. Gimp doesn't support more than 8-bit per color channel nor non-RGB color spaces (like Lab).

Answer (score 1):

You may find some use in [GIMPshop](http://www.gimpshop.com/), mostly a UI modification for GIMP which makes it feel a lot more like PS.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a non-exhaustive list of variants [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIMP#Variants). GIMPhoto is based on a more recent version of GIMP than GIMPshop.